# Passing a value from PartialView to parent View

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am trying to add pagination with infinite scrolling to my web application. I'm just having one problem, which is that I need to pass a value to a controller action method to fetch the next page in the sequence.

The action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string nextCursorMark)
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        var page = GetPagedArticles(15, "*:*", nextCursorMark);
        return PartialView("_ArticlesPartial", page);
    }
    else
    {
        var page = GetPagedArticles(30, "*:*");
        return View(page);   
    }
}
```

`page` contains the string which I need to pass on. When the View is rendered, the value is added from that view by javascript, which means that the next request (the partial) is of course fetched correctly. The problem is that all subsequent requests are returning the same value, as I can't figure out how to pass on the value (either using MVC or javascript).

The script added to the View (most code omitted):

```
@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && !hasData && !inProgress) {
            $.ajax("@Url.Action("Index", "Articles", new { nextCursorMark = Model.CurserMark })", {
              ...
            }});
</script>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Razor is parsed on the server before it is sent to the view so

```
$.ajax("@Url.Action("Index", "Articles", new { nextCursorMark = Model.CurserMark })"
```

is evaluating to the url to `'/Articles/Index/#` where # is the **initial** value of `CursorMark` when the page is first loaded.

You need to include a variable that you can increment with each call

```
var cursor = '@Model.CursorMark'; // initial value
....
$.ajax('@Url.Action("Index", "Articles")', { newCursorMark: cursor } {
  // update the DOM
  ....
  cursor += someIncrement; // increment the value for the next call
}});
```

Comment: Yes, I know. The problem with that is that the value is some kind of a hashed string value that is auto generated whenever a new page is requested. So unfortunately it is not as simple as doing a increment of that variable. Would it be possible to update the view without appending the whole page to itself with the new data, instead of returning a partial view?

Comment: No, because you need to pass an updated value for `newCursorMark` (otherwise its just going to repeat the same view). Why does it need to be hashed string? How is it generated? When is is generated?

Comment: It is a string generated by SOLR as a pointer to the next sequence of data in its index. It is the most efficient way of doing deep pagination with SOLR.

Comment: If that value is generated in the `Index()` method, perhaps you could pass it to the partial view and render a hidden input, then when you update the DOM in the ajax call, get the value of the input, assign it to the `cursor` variable, then delete the hidden input (so its ID does not conflict with the input from the next call)